Could not set unknown property 'enableV3Signing' error while enabling v3 signing Android APK File
Gradle version is 6.2. I'm using defauly v1 signing in my android application. Now I'm trying to enable v2 and v3 by adding.
android {
   ...
   signingConfigs {
      release {
          ...
          enableV3Signing = true
      }
   }
}

 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard- 
             rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
}

I've enabled v2 and v3 in signingConfig and added it in buildTypes. Gradle accepts v1 and v2 but not v3. I get the below error while syncing the gradle.
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not set unknown property 'enableV3Signing' for SigningConfig_Decorated{name=release, storeFile=/Users/admin/Documents/projects//*****//*****/android/app/my-release-key.keystore, storePassword=/*****, keyAlias=/*****, keyPassword=/*****, storeType=/*****, v1SigningEnabled=false, v2SigningEnabled=true} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.SigningConfig.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
    at 
    ... 128 more

